# How to calculate the number of cells in different cell clusters with Seurat v3?

Tags: scrnaseq

I was supposed to use the code below to get the number of cells per cluster. The code works with Seurat version 2, but while using version 3 I got the error `no slot of name "ident" for this object of class "Seurat"`. Does anyone have any idea about how to deal with this?

```
# Calculate number of cells per cluster from object@ident

cell.num <- table(shox2crepos_mtmg@ident)

# Add cell number per cluster to cluster labels

ClusterLabels = paste("Cluster", names(cell.num), paste0("(n = ", cell.num, ")"))

# Order legend labels in plot in the same order as 'ClusterLabels'

ClusterBreaks = names(cell.num)

# Plot tSNE with new legend labels for clusters

TSNEPlot(object = shox2crepos_mtmg, do.return = T) +
  scale_colour_discrete(breaks = ClusterBreaks,
                        labels = ClusterLabels) +
  labs(x = "t-SNE 1",
       y = "t-SNE 2")
```

Comment: The official seurat website (https://satijalab.org/seurat/essential_commands.html) has a `cheat sheet` page with all the different commands between `v2` and `v3` (`Seurat v2.X vs v3.X`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "identities" can be accessed with the `Idents()` function in Seurat v3.

You should change `cell.num <- table(shox2crepos_mtmg@ident)` to

`cell.num <- table(Idents(shox2crepos_mtmg))`